# How to fetch data using Retrofit in Listview

Tags: android, listview, retrofit2

I am getting a nullPointException in my adapter class.

I want to get contact from server containing name and email.
my Contact class is

```
public class Contact {

@SerializedName("name")
private String Name;

@SerializedName("email")
private String Email;


public String getName() {
    return Name;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return Email;
}
```

}

ApiClient CLass

```
public class ApiClient {

private static final String BASE_URL = "http://192.168.43.88/ContactApp/";
public static Retrofit retrofit = null;

public static Retrofit getApiClient (){

    if (retrofit == null){
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
    }

    return retrofit;
}
```

}

this is an adapter class where I am getting **null pointer exception in infalter**

public class RetrofitItemAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

```
Context mContext;
private List<Contact> mContact;
RecyclerView.ViewHolder vh = null;

//Constructor


public RetrofitItemAdapter(List<Contact> mContact) {

    this.mContact = mContact;
}


public  class ViewHolder {

    public TextView tvName;
    public TextView tvEmail;


}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mContact.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mContact.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    View vi = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {

        LayoutInflater inflater;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );

        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_retrofit_items, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.tvName  = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tv_ret_name);
        holder.tvEmail  = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tv_ret_email);


        vi.setTag(holder);

    } else
        holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();

    // now set your text view here like

   // holder.tvName.setText("Bla Bla Bla");

    holder.tvName.setText(mContact.get(position).getName());
    holder.tvEmail.setText(mContact.get(position).getEmail());


    // return your view
    return vi;
```

and finally my main class is

```
public class RetrofitDemo extends AppCompatActivity {

private ListView listView;
private List<Contact> contacts;
private RetrofitItemAdapter adapter;
private ApiInterface apiInterface;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_retrofit_demo);

    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv_retrofitData);

    apiInterface = ApiClient.getApiClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
    Call<List<Contact>> call = apiInterface.getContacts();

    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Contact>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Contact>> call, Response<List<Contact>> response) {

            contacts = response.body();

            adapter = new RetrofitItemAdapter(contacts);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Contact>> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });

}
```

}

**Logcat error**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                             Process: com.example.admin.myapplication, PID: 2528
                                             java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                 at com.example.admin.myapplication.RetrofitItemAdapter.getView(RetrofitItemAdapter.java:66)
                                                 at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java)
                                                 at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1790)
                                                 at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:691)
                                                 at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:752)
                                                 at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1630)
                                                 at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java)
                                                 at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14834)
                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
                                                 at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1055)
                                                 at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14834)
                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
                                                 at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
                                                 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
                                                 at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14834)
                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:437)
                                                 at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14834)
                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
                                                 at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
                                                 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
                                                 at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14834)
                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
                                                 at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14834)
                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
                                                 at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
                                                 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
                                                 at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14834)
                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1988)
                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1745)
                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1001)
                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5623)
                                                 at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
                                                 at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
                                                 at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
                                                 at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5241)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:818)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**where is my mistake please help me 
Thanks**

Comment: please share your logcat output with the error you get

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 Process: com.example.admin.myapplication, PID: 2528
                                                 java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                     at com.example.admin.myapplication.RetrofitItemAdapter.getView(RetrofitItemAdapter.java:66)
                                                     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java)

Comment: well you see that the crash appears in your RetrofitItemAdapter.‌​java at line 66. now if you would share more logcat output maybe we can see the reason why there is a nullpointer. since I guess line 66 is somewhere different in your file than in the ones you posted since you didn't include the imports.

Comment: i am getting error in this line
 inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );

Comment: and what does it say exactly? it says that it is at obtainView... you have to share more from the logcat output otherwise no one will be able to help you^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not setting the context object created in your Adaptor.

You need to set that up by passing activity context along with the contacts you are passing onto the adaptor

```
public RetrofitItemAdapter(List<Contact> mContact, Context context) {
   this.mContact = mContact;
   this.mContext = context;
}
```

And in activity

```
  adapter = new RetrofitItemAdapter(contacts, RetrofitDemo.this);
  listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Thanks Sir... my program is running now :)

Comment: Glad it helped!! :) happy coding @SayedRizwanHashmi